# Jasper Page break on New Field/Variable

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I am working on a jasper report, and I am trying to figure out a way for the report to page break on a variable change.  The variable is actually a Field, and I put the value of the field in a variable.

Now, the Jasper Reports website has an example on how to break it by count like this

```
<groupExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($V{BreakGroup_COUNT}.intValue()
> 5)]] ></groupExpression>
```

However, I am not sure of any way to compare the previous or next value and breaking after that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just want the report to start a new page when $F{MyField} changes value.

In this case simply create a group with 'Group Expression': `$F{MyField}`

Tick the option 'Start on a new page' for the group. There is no need for a variable.

Comment: How do you create a group in iReports 4.7? I just updated from 2.0 and don't see it anywhere.  There is an option to add to group when I right click, but from there I see nothing indicating a group anywhere.

Comment: Or would you know how to do this just via code?  In the old version of iRepors I was using, when I created a new group, the only options I had after hitting next was to insert a header and footer for the group.  I had no options for Start new page, etc.  On Jasper 4.7, I am not seeing any option to create a group at all, and it has to be compatable with 3.0.1 Jasper for where I work and it won't save.

Comment: Alright, well I got it to break on group change, however, even when the numbers are the same it still page breaks.  I guess it sees every new set of data as a group change even if the number stays the same.

Comment: You'll have to provide a more detailed example to make this completely clear. But I'm glad it's working well so far.

Answer (score 0):

Select the header of the group in the Document Structure window, and then select in the Properties window Start on New Page.